# Grab files, published on a web page, programmatically

Tags: python, objective-c, download, web-scraping

I want to programmatically get a list of published zip files from one web site, unpack them and get a folder with some kind of text files on my desktop folder.

It is a list of dictionaries in XDXF format, published here http://dicto.org.ru/xdxf.html and downloaded eventually from SourceForge.

I am a beginner in web technologies, but good at Objective-C. I seek for any recommendations, which approach should I use, which languages and which articles can I read on this topic. I will not abuse that web sites, I just want to automate downloading of about 100 files and unzipping them. I do not want to do this manually. I have heard that some kind of this task is possible using Python.

As far, as I know, I can get a list of links to automatic download from that page. What is the best method to get them? Using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modules like [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize) to retrieve and scrap web pages, as well as files.  For unzipping, you can use the standard module [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile).

Comment: Which modules particularly?

Comment: @wzbozon  Was collecting the URL references. Happy now? :-)